# Representing one-many data in a query in one row in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database with two tables: `Users`, `Items`

`Users` looks like this:

```
userId     uniqueindentifier
username   nvarchar
```

`Items` looks like this:

```
userId     uniqueidentifier
itemName   nvarchar
```

So each user can have several items.

I need to do a query that returns a user. I could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users JOIN Items on Users.UserId = Items.UserId
WHERE UserId = 1
```

If user 1 has 2 items, the query will return something like this:

```
UserId    userName    ItemName
1         Oliver      Apple
1         Oliver      Orange
```

I want the query to return something like this:

```
UserId    userName    ItemNames
1         Oliver      Apple, Orange
```

Or even better, something like this:

```
UserId    userName    ItemName1    ItemName2
1         Oliver      Apple        Orange
```

Is it possible to achieve this? The reason I want to do it this way is because if I do a query with `SELECT TOP 50`, I want to return 50 distinct users, not (for example) 18 users in 50 rows, with several items per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `PIVOT` and `ROW_NUMBER` to pivot on if there was a known max number of columns. Or `XML PATH` to simulate [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) for the delimited list. Both of these are covered in other SO questions.

You don't need to do this though to achieve the result stated in your last sentence. You can just do

```
;WITH TopUsers As
(
SELECT TOP (50) *
FROM Users
ORDER BY UserId
)

SELECT * 
FROM TopUsers 
    JOIN Items on TopUsers.UserId = Items.UserId
```